# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape error

Tags: python, csv

So I am trying to make a prediction application and i found the data i need for it. But, i needed to import that data. It is stored in a csv file and it keeps giving me the error 'SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape'

Here is the code (python)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

sonar_data = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\adity\Onedrive\Documents\Coding\pandas minerocks.csv', header=None)
```

I need to use minerocks.csv but if i try to do double \ then it says there is no file even if i try to put an r at the starting of the path it dosent work. Please help

I was trying to access a csv file

Comment: Put the "r" back in to get rid of the syntax error. Now its a question of whether you got the path right. If you use the path on the command line, does it work? You mention a file "minerocks.csv", but your code is looking for a file "pandas minerocks.csv". Which is correct?

Comment: I tried it but it gave me the error No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\adity\\Onedrive\\Documents\\Coding\\pandas\\minerocks.csv'

Comment: it just adds an extra \ even if i dont put it

Comment: `print('C:\\Users\\adity\\Onedrive\\Documents\\Coding\\pandas\\minerocks.csv')` would print out `C:\Users\adity\Onedrive\Documents\Coding\pandas\minerocks.csv`. If you open a command prompt and run `dir C:\Users\adity\Onedrive\Documents\Coding\pandas\minerocks.csv`, do you see the file?

Comment: yeah i see the file

Comment: I don't have any explanation. You could simplify the test by a simple one line script `open('C:\\Users\\adity\\Onedrive\\Documents\\Coding\\pandas\\minerocks.csv')` - now you've gotten rid of everything but a simple open. You are running this on your local machine, right? Not a jupyter notebook running on a different machine, or some other remote execution environment?

Comment: im running it on colab.reasearch.google

Comment: It seems like you have a file on your local machine, which isn't going to be seen by colab. You could mount google drive on your local machine and copy the CSV there. Then, mount drive on your colab instance and access it. It will have a different path.

Comment: i tried it but i got an error btw ignore essays in dlh imagine it as any folder for now lol : Operation not supported: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Essays in DLH/Copy of sonar data.gsheet'